# memory error when using cv::dct of opencv

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I have a function using opencv.

```
Mat CalPHashCode(Mat image)
{
    Mat floatImage, imageDct,temp;
    resize(image, temp, Size(32, 32));  
    temp.convertTo(floatImage, CV_32FC1);
    dct(floatImage, imageDct);
    Rect roi(0, 0, 8, 8);
    Scalar imageMean = mean(imageDct(roi));
    return (imageDct(roi) > imageMean[0]);
}
```

When it runs to the dct function "dct(floatImage, imageDct)", I got a error message: "Unhandled exception at at 0x76DA2EEC in PerceptualHash.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00C3E108."

I don't know why. Can anyone help?
It's opencv2.4.7, visual studio 2012, windows 8 64, project is Win32,Debug mode.

Comment: Usually a more specific error message gets printed to the console of the running program when an `cv::Exception` is thrown. What does that say? If not have you tried surrounding your code in a `try`/`catch` and reading the message of the thrown exception?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to initialize imageDct before using it as a param in dct.

Try this:

```
imageDct = Mat( floatImage.rows, floatImage.cols, floatImage.type() );
```

before calling dct.

Comment: You don't need to initialize the `Mat` you are saving the coefficients to